# Install FOS UserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm following a tutorial to install this FOSUserBundle to my project.
I got my information from this french tutorial: http://www.tutodidacte.com/symfony2-installer-fosuserbundle

So I did those commands:

```
php ./composer.phar require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0@dev" 
php composer.phar update
```

Then I created a new Bundle,

```
php bin/console generate:bundle
Bundle Namespace : Kingdom/UserBundle
```

But after doing that, in the AppKernel i can see the new UserBundle, mais the FOSUserBundle isn't here.

I try to add it by myself writting it in the file; but after when i try to create an entity we can see something is clearly wrong.

Sorry for the presentation of this below...I haven't succeed to print it correctly.

> php bin/console generate:doctrine:entity

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\I
nvalidConfigurationException' with message 'The child node "db_driver" at path "
fos_user" must be configured.' in C:\wamp\www\Kingdom\vendor\symfony\symfony\src
\Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ArrayNode.php:240
Stack trace:

## 0 C:\wamp\www\Kingdom\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Config\Defin

ition\BaseNode.php(303): Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ArrayNode->finalize
Value(Array)

## 1 C:\wamp\www\Kingdom\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Config\Defin

ition\Processor.php(37): Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\BaseNode->finalize(
Array)

## 2 C:\wamp\www\Kingdom\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Config\Defin

ition\Processor.php(50): Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Processor->process(
Object(Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ArrayNode), Array)

## 3 C:\wamp\www\Kingdom\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\DependencyInjection\F

OSUserExtension.php(51): Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Processor->processC
onfigur in C:\wamp\www\Kingdom\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Conf
ig\Definition\ArrayNode.php on line 240

Comment: try to configure config.yml correctly, if It doesn't work again try to post your config.yml file here please

Comment: How do I know if the config.yml is correctly configured ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't properly configured the bundle. Follow the steps here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

In your case, it seems you are missing at least this:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-5-configure-the-fosuserbundle

EDIT: After reading your question again, it seems you're not loading the bundle properly, as described here:
http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-2-enable-the-bundle

Comment: Ok, but without speaking of settings, after the step 1, I should be able to find the FOSUserBundle folder inside my application i think no ? Because in fact I can't see it. So i'm not sure the step 1 works fine for me. 

I'll check another time as soon as I get back home. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but not sure if you're looking at the right place. If should be within your vendor folder, in vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle. It's up to you to load it in your AppKernel.php, adding:

            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),

Comment: Ok, so I might have been doing something wrong. I'll try it tonight and I'll came back here if I have more issues.

Answer (score 0):

After Installation A bundle needs to be enabled in AppKernel.php file. FOSUserBundle needs a bit of configuration to make it work properly I have written a simple and easy guide on it: 
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/implement-fosuserbundle-in-symfony-3-1/

**Installation:**

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0@dev"
```

**Enabling Bundle in AppKernel.php**

After installing FOSUserBundle you must enable it in the project. Go to app/config/AppKernel.php and add the highlighted line in the bundles array.

```
$bundles = [
...
new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
]
```

**Create User Entity**

Create the `User` entity as you are creating above :)

**Configuring Security.yml file**

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

**Configure FOSUserBundle in a Config**

Add this config in **config.yml**

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
```

**Importing Route files of FOSUserBundle**

Add this to import routes in **Routing.yml**

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

**Updating Database Schema**

The last step is to update the database schema to create table in the database.

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Now move to the app URL add **/login** in it you will see the login page.

[image]

Comment: The thing is...as soon as i want to create the User bundle, i have this issue: " The child node "db_driver" at path "fos_user" must be configured"
So I tried to update the config.yml first but the result is the same. And this happens for every command, i try to clear cache as well and i have this error :(

Comment: Clear symfony cache with this command `rm -fr var/cache/*` and then try to create your bundle again.

Comment: It works now but it wasn't from cache..i had to add an abject from_email inside fos_user in the config.yml. Don't know why but it works fine now.

One more thing, i have to use the login view from the bundle or may be i can just extend that view to create my own ? Because right now i have no design and the field name are different from mine.

Comment: I did write one article on that see if this can help you: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/overriding-default-fosuserbundle-templates